# How to include jplayer.js on all pages

Tags: javascript

I am using module - jplayer (http://drupal.org/project/jplayer), in the jplayer.module i've found this piece of code, since i am very weak in php i need a help :)

```
/**
 * Add the jPlayer library to the page.
 *
 * @param $add
 *   By default this function will add jPlayer to the page JavaScript array
 *   directly. If wanting to store the jPlayer file as an #attached property,
 *   set this to FALSE and jplayer_add() will only return the needed array
 *   suitable for use as an #attached property.
 */
function jplayer_add($add = TRUE) {
  static $added = FALSE;

  $directory = variable_get('jplayer_directory', 'sites/all/libraries/jplayer');
  $return = FALSE;
  if (file_exists($directory . '/jquery.jplayer.min.js')) {
    $filepath = $directory . '/jquery.jplayer.min.js';
  }
  elseif (file_exists($directory . '/jquery.jplayer.js')) {
    $filepath = $directory . '/jquery.jplayer.js';
  }

  if (isset($filepath)) {
    $jplayer_js = jplayer_get_file_path('jplayer.js');    
    $jplayer_css = jplayer_get_file_path('jplayer.css'); 
    $settings = array('jPlayer' => array(
      'swfPath' => base_path() . variable_get('jplayer_directory', 'sites/all/libraries/jplayer'),
      'autoPlay' => (int) variable_get('jplayer_autoplay', ''),
    ));
    if ($add) {
      drupal_add_js($filepath);
      drupal_add_js($jplayer_js);
      drupal_add_css($jplayer_css);
      if (!$added) {
        drupal_add_js($settings, 'setting');
        $added = TRUE;
      }
    }
    $return = array(
      'js' => array(
        array('data' => $filepath),
        array('data' => $jplayer_js),
        array('data' => $settings, 'type' => 'setting'),
      ),
      'css' => array(
        array('data' => $jplayer_css),
      ),
    );
  }

  return $return;
}
```

What should i modify in this code to show .js files on every page, not only when a node with a player loaded.

**UPDATED.** The question is - what to modify in this code to attach jplayer js files on every page, not when im viewing a node with a jquery player.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't modify third party code (Drupal core or contrib modules and themes). As it jeopardize future updates of your site. See https://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core and http://joshuabrauer.com/2008/07/dont-hack-core-and-dont-hack-contrib-unless-you-have.

Comment: i won't update this site in a future...

Comment: Unless this is a site with a very short lifespan, you (or somebody) will have to update it, if only for security updates. Call it maintenance if you like, but it will happen.

Comment: Ok, my situation is next: this module loads own .js files only when u're viewing a node with a jplayer, i'm printing out this node in a page.tpl.php, so then jplayer scripts won't loading -> player not working. Simply including jplayer.js in info file won't work.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to add a JS file to your theme is to add it in the `.info` file:

```
scripts[] = js/my_script.js
```

Be sure to put your js file in a js folder inside your folder's theme.

**Reference**: [Adding JavaScript to your theme or module](http://drupal.org/node/304255)  *(works in D7 too)*

Comment: Well, i already knew about this, thanks. But then how to disable including javascripts in this module then?

Comment: I think you can use [hook_js_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7) (D7) or [JS Alter](http://drupal.org/project/jsalter) (D6) to remove JS added by your module.

Answer (score 1):

Use [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_init/6)

> this hook is a typical place for modules to add CSS or JS that should be present on every page. This hook is not run on cached pages - though CSS or JS added this way will be present on a cached page.

Comment: There's no hook init functions.

Comment: No there is no hook_init() function, this is a a hook any module can implement, see https://drupal.org/node/292

Comment: can u show me an example with a code in the my question?